# Android how i can achieve the usage details of sms,minutes etc in the rounded circle like the mentioned image

Tags: android, android-activity

How i can achieve this type of functionality which i have mentioned in the following image with the Red Arrow,any example or sample code will be help alot.

[image]

Comment: Check : https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1000, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint myPaint =new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        myPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.midnight_blue));
        canvas.drawArc(new RectF(0, 0, 300, 300), 40, 280, false, myPaint);
        myPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));
        canvas.drawArc(new RectF(0, 0, 300, 300),-30, 60, false, myPaint);
```

`R.color.midnight_blue` and `R.color.Green` is my color and you can use yours

You can draw as much arc as you want,control the stroke width with `Paint.setStrokeWidth(float f);`

Here is api of drawArc method:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Comment: kindly share your usage of colors that how u can use it,can i put the color in res folder?

Comment: Yes,in res folder's color.xml(if it doesn't exist,you can create it).In this file you can declare the color resources and in Java code get it by getResource().getColor(R.color.yourColorName)